# socket.io version with an old nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

Have to work on a WebOS display with built-in NodeJS version 0.10.x

So far, can use Node websocket version 1.0.28 to communicate between devices.
However I like to know if I can swap this websocket with socket.io ?
Can somebody give recommendation which socket.io version compatible with this old NodeJS ?

As Information :

- WebOS 2.0 have NodeJS 0.10.25
- WebOS 3.0 have NodeJS 0.12.2
- WebOS 4.x have NodeJS 6.11.2
- WebOS 6.0 have NodeJS 8.12.0

Comment: Why do you need socket.io? Websockets are way lighter. If it's not an option, try to find a version that was released when Node 0.10 was still actively maintained?

Comment: I tried examining package.json file of socket.io , however not all contain node engines information. 
Once i read on socket.io 0.9.xx package.json file  , it stated engines node >= 0.4.0 ... 
this is way too old. 

If possible I want to find latest socket.io that still compatible with Node 0.12.2 ...

Comment: I would suggest you pick a version, try it out and if it doens't work try the previous major version and repeat.